# Why the ip address captured by HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR is diferrent from the address shown in the device

Tags: python, django, ip

I want some clarification regarding IP address captured by `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`. In my website I am storing the IP address of the visitors to count the number of visits.

The code that I am using for this is this function is used to capture the IP:

```
def get_ip(request):

    try:
        ip_forward = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if ip_forward:
            ip = ip_forward.split(",")[0]
            print("returning forwarded for ip address", ip)

        elif request.META.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP'):
            ip = request.META.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP')
            print ("returning REAL_IP ", ip)

        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            print("returning remote address ", ip)

    except:
        ip= ""
    
    return ip
```

after the above function is called on the index view it is then passed to this function for storing the IP:

```
def visitor_count(ip):

    visitor = VisitorCount()

    visitor.ip = ip
    visitor.date_of_record = datetime.now()

    if VisitorCount.objects.all().filter(ip = visitor.ip ,date_of_record__icontains= datetime.today().date()).exists():
        pass
        print("the ip", visitor.ip,"recorded on", visitor.date_of_record ,"already exists and wil not be saved")
    else:
        print('this is the ip address of the user that has been saved', visitor.ip)

        visitor.save()
    return "saved"
```

as you can see it prints what it is doing. My site is hosted in `heroku` (if that matters). I went through some SatckOverflow questions but could not find an ans to what I wanted to.

Now, suppose when I am going to the site, and check the logs in `heroku`, I find this:

> "returning forwarded for ip address 103.38.89.218"

where as my IP address shown in the device is 192.168.3.1. Thus the IP address that eventually gets stored is 103.38.89.218.

Why is this so? Why it is not capturing the address shown by my device. Or to be specific how to capture the IP address shown in my device.

And out of curiosity I want to ask, if some day I want to block the access to my site from users coming form certain IP address, will I be needing the address shown by my device or the one captured by `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` will do the work.

Comment: The internet facing IP address of your device does not start with `192.168`, that's a private address range usually used by your local network

Comment: `192.168.3.1` is an internal address in the devices' local network and has no meaning outside the local network itself. `103.38.89.218` is the IP from your ISP that the local network uses for all communication on the Internet. If you want to block things, the ISP's address is what you want to use since that's a closer approximation of a single user, blocking a user based on a local network address (which may be used on millions of different local networks) wouldn't really work.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Thank you, for clearing my doubts'